# Nested php includes get commented out

Tags: php, include, external

I've written a simple function to switch languages on my site.

domainname.com/minis/ is my regular blog

domainname.com/minis-eng/ is the english version

Here's the switcher, it works alright:

```
<?php
echo '<a href="';
if (strpos(basename(getcwd()),'eng') !== false)
    {
        $subject = basename(getcwd());
        $search = '-eng';
        $trimmed = str_replace($search, '', $subject);
        echo '/', $trimmed, '/' , basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '">Polski</a>';
    }
else
    {echo '/', basename(getcwd()), '-eng/', basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '">English</a>';}
?>
```

Now when I place it in an external php and include it in the main index.php- it works alright too. However, I'm using a couple of external .php files to place repeated elements. So index.php looks more or less like this:

- include head.php
- include body.php (this contains the navigation menu)
- main content
- include footer.php

Now I'd love to place langswitcher.php in my root directory, and then place this in my body.php:

```
<?php
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
include (dirname(ROOT). '/langswitcher.php');
?>
```

However, apparently the php including code in an included .php doesn't get parsed- in the final result this part is simply written as is and commented out.

Is there anything I can do to make this "included include" get parsed?

Thanks in advance for your help and do let me know if I wasn't clear anywhere.

Comment: A nested include should work, therefore I think we need to see the code that include body.php as well.

Comment: Ahhhh I can't believe how dumb I was being. I wasn't actually including body.php, I was PRINTING it! (a remnant of the past, when I was beginning to learn basic php). Thanks, now I know what to work on!